# Is there a canonical map $A\otimes B \to A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.
Let $\rho: R \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism and  $A$ a $B$-module.
Then **is there a canonical map $A\otimes_R B \to A$?**

For example,  this is needed for understanding the definition of relative ampleness.   Let $f: X \longrightarrow T$ be a proper mapping of algebraic varieties or schemes, and let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$.
$L$ is very ample relative to $f$, or $f$-very ample, if the canonical map
$$
\rho: f^{*} f_{*} L \longrightarrow L
$$
is  surjective and  ........

First we only have the canonical map
$$
\rho: f^{-1} f_{*} L \longrightarrow L .
$$
Then if we want get a map $$
\rho: f^{*} f_{*} L \longrightarrow L,
$$
we should need a canonical map $A\otimes_R B \to A$?

Comment: Well, there's the zero map...for what purpose do you want this canonical map?

Comment: @EricWofsey  Thank you, I have add the motivation in the post.   Just for understanding $\rho: f^{*} f_{*} L \longrightarrow L$.

Comment: Do you want your map to be a morphism of R-modules?

Comment: @ErikD  it'd better be  a morphism of $B$-module.

Answer (score 5):

The canonical map referred to in this context is just the multiplication map $A\otimes_R B\to A$ defined by $a\otimes b\mapsto ba$ (where $ba$ is defined using the $B$-module structure of $A$).  This is the counit of the adjunction between $-\otimes_R B$ and the forgetful functor from $B$-modules to $R$-modules, which is what the adjunction between the functors of sheaves $f^*$ and $f_*$ is for affine schemes.

Comment: For this adjunction to hold, you need $B$ to be projective over $R$, right?

Comment: No, why would that be necessary?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. You need it for the Eckmann-Shapiro lemma (about the Ext:s), but not for the adjunction itself.